# MYSQL: Search for User ID in one table to search for data in 2 other tables, then show data from all 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

I have a database with entries similar to the following...

```
users:
+-----+------+----------+---------+-------+
| UID | Name |  Addr    |  City   | State |
+-----+------+----------+---------+-------+
|   1 | John | 101 Main | Austin  | TX    |
|   2 | John | 101 Main | Houston | TX    |
|   3 | John | 101 Main | Del Rio | TX    |
|   4 | John | 101 Main | Houston | TX    |
+-----+------+----------+---------+-------+

verification:
+-----+---------------+--------------+
| UID | LicenseFirst3 | LicenseLast3 |
+-----+---------------+--------------+
|   1 |           554 |          122 |
|   2 |           556 |          345 |
|   3 |           555 |          382 |
|   4 |           555 |          108 |
+-----+---------------+--------------+

section_user_map:
+-----+-----------+---------------------+
| UID | SectionID |    CompleteDate     |
+-----+-----------+---------------------+
|   1 |        65 | 2012-05-12 05:05:15 |
|   2 |        72 | 2012-05-06 14:03:15 |
|   3 |        65 | 2012-05-09 16:13:15 |
|   4 |        72 | 2012-05-06 18:14:15 |
+-----+-----------+---------------------+
```

I need to be able to search for students who completed section 65 between noon on day X and noon on day Y. I also need to show the student's name, address, city, state and first and last three digits of their license number. I believe this will require both a left join and union command but it's getting a bit too complicated to formulate.

Comment: Could you post the SQL you've written so far, too?

Comment: Well, show us what you've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   section_user_map
  JOIN users        USING (UID)
  JOIN verification USING (UID)
WHERE  SectionID = 65
   AND CompleteDate BETWEEN '2012-05-09 12:00:00'
                        AND '2012-05-11 12:00:00'
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25a7c/1/0).

No `UNION` required.  Outer join would only be required if you still want to return results for users who do not exist in one (or both) of the `users` or `verification` tables.